# Access property of a object without needing to cast it

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have the following three classes

```
public class Base
{
    string name;
}

public class Foo : Base
{
    int value;
}

public class Bar : Base
{
    double value;
}
```

This is what I'm attempting

```
Base current = null;

if (somecondition)
    current = new Foo();
else
    current = new Bar();

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    current.value = i;           
}
```

The problem is VS 2010 shows an error in the loop body because `Base` doesn't have a property `value`.

Now, I could workaround this issue by this way:

```
Base current = null;
bool isBar = true;

if (somecondition)
{
    current = new Foo();
    isBar = false;
}
else
    current = new Bar();

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    if (isBar)
        (current as Bar).value = i;          
    else
        (current as Foo).value = i;
}
```

But I was hoping for a better solution because once the loop starts iterating, the type of `current` isn't going to change, yet I am going to test the type and accordingly cast it for each iteration.

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example? What are you actually trying to do by setting these values?

Comment: I agree with @casablanca. You might get answers that are far more helpful if you provided your actual use case scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making the fields accessible (or exposing them as accessible properties instead), your options are:

- Make your base class abstract, with an abstract method or property to set the value (and possibly return it) - the problem here is that you can't easily do that when the two types are different
- Create an interface to do the same sort of thing, and cast to the interface
- Just cast as you are now
- Use `dynamic` if you're using C# 4 - just declare `current` as `dynamic`, and you can assign to `current.value` and the compiler will insert code to work it out at execution time
- Redesign your code / inheritance hierarchy

Personally I would at least consider the last approach - is inheritance definitely appropriate here? Do the two types for `value` really need to be different? Do they have the same *meaning*, and if so would it make sense to push the value to the base class and potentially make it generic if you need different types?

Comment: If these are all the options I have, I suppose I'll just have to stick with casting for now. Thanks for laying out my options clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead of using a base class create an interface that has Value as a property and then have Foo and Bar implement that interface.

Comment: This won't work because `value` has different types in `Foo` and `Bar`.

Comment: It could be a property `IntValue` of type `int` which is converted as necessary by the subclass's implementation.

Comment: In this case you could get it to work you would just need to not use an automatic property.

Comment: @perelman: That would indeed work, but we don't yet know the OP's use case and whether this would help him.

Answer (score 0):

First, your "value" fields are not exposed as public.

Second, I don't think you won't get away from explicit casting here. Just imaging that your Bar class look like this:

```
   public class Bar : Base
   {
    public string value;
   }
```